# Escaping the "+" sign in jstl

Tags: jsp, controller, escaping, jstl

I've some problems in passing values from a jsp (with jstl) to a controller that will use the parameter to perform a query.
Here is the code:

```
<c:set var="pkey">"${entry.name}";"${entry.surname}";"${entry.phone}"</c:set>
```

and

```
<c:set var="name" value="${entry.name}"/>
<c:set var="surname" value="${entry.surname}"/>
<c:set var="phone" value="${entry.phone}"/>
<c:set var="pkey">"${name}";"${surname}";"${phone}"</c:set>
```

are supposed to be equivalent right?
Keep in mind that phone is something like "+digits digits digits".
Now, after the pkey has been "encapsulated", I send it to the controller with

```
 <a href="Controller?action=delete&pkey=
                    <c:out value="${pkey}"/>" onclick="del()">Delete</a>
```

If I check the query string, it contains the parameter as they should be, with the "+" of the phone at its place.
When the request goes to the controller, getting the pkey with getParameter("pkey") results in loosing the "+" and gaining a blank space, thus every query I perform in the database with it fails. 
What is wrong with my code? I've tried to search how to escape special symbols (I found an escapeXML that has been of no help), with no luck.

The second problem is not a problem actually (since I've worked it around), but I would like to know why is that: during the same encapsulation and sending, the "name" parameter shows some blank spaces in the variable before the value (I see them in the query string). Not a big deal, I've just put a .trim() when getting the parameter, but why all that blank spaces?

Thank you

Marco Dalena

Answer (score 1, accepted):

- Use [Tag url `<c:url>`](http://docs.oracle.com/javaee/5/jstl/1.1/docs/tlddocs/c/url.html), creates a URL with optional query parameters.
- Use [Tag param `<c:param>`](http://docs.oracle.com/javaee/5/jstl/1.1/docs/tlddocs/c/param.html) to pass parameters along with URL

Here is code

```
<c:url value="Controller" var="myURL">
  <c:param name="action" value="delete"/>
  <c:param name="pkey" value="${pkey}"/>
</c:url>
```

Then pass this URL to the anchor tag

```
<a href="${myURL}" onclick="del()">Delete</a>
```

---

The `<c:url> tag` is used to generate URLs. In particular, this tag provides three elements of functionality that are particularly important when constructing URLs for J2EE Web applications:

- Prepending the name of the current servlet context
- URL re-writing for session management
- URL encoding of request-parameter names and values

#### Syntax for the `<c:url>` action:

```
<c:url value="expression" context="expression" var="name" scope="scope">
  <c:param name="expression" value="expression"/>
   ...
</c:url>
```

- The `value` attribute is used to specify a base URL, which the tag then transforms as necessary. If this base URL starts with a forward slash, then a servlet context name will be prepended.
- An explicit context name can be provided using the `context` attribute. If this attribute is omitted, then the name of the current servlet context will be used.
- URL rewriting is automatically performed by the `<c:url>` action. If the JSP container detects a cookie storing the user's current session ID, no rewriting is necessary. If no such cookie is present, however, all URLs generated by `<c:url>` will be rewritten to encode the session ID. Note that if an appropriate cookie is present in subsequent requests, `<c:url>` will stop rewriting URLs to include this ID.
- If a value is supplied for the `var` attribute (optionally accompanied by a corresponding value for the scope attribute), the generated URL will be assigned as the value of the specified scoped variable. Otherwise, the resulting URL will be output using the current `JspWriter`.
- If any request parameters are specified through nested `<c:param>` tags, then their names and values will be appended to the generated URL using the standard notation for HTTP GET requests. In addition, **URL encoding is performed**.

Read more at [jstl-core](http://heavyz.sourceforge.net/homepage/homepage_zh/comp/notes/jstl-core.html)

Comment: Cool, thank you! I've never used jstl before, I'm basically learning these days. Thank you so much.

Answer (score 0):

The plus sign is a special character for the query string mechanism as the ampersand join the paramaters, the only way I think you could send the plus is to send the value %2B that represents the plus sign so with the url:

```
http://mysite/myapp/controller?param1=a%2Bb
```

When you get the value of the param1 in your controller it will be `a+b`, so you could create a function to encode the plus sign to the value %2B or just simple use the replace function of the string, I hope this will help you.

Comment: Thank you, but I prefer the solution @Aniket gave to me.